# Running optional commands in a gitlab-ci.yml's stage's "script"?

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the below stage that will run a maven build on my java code, which works fine. However I have multiple Java projects running this same maven build, and one of the Java projects needs additional commands to be run through that `script`.

For example the first command in the `script` needs to be a `npm i yarn`, but only for a single project. How would I use variables to add this?

```
build maven:
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 3 day      # don't keep these around for long
    paths:
      - target/
  script:
    - echo "PIPELINE_DEFAULT_IMAGE - ${PIPELINE_DEFAULT_IMAGE}"
    - mvn -version
    - mvn package -Pprod -DskipTests=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `CI_PROJECT_NAME` contains the name of the project.

Example `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
myjob:
  script:
    - if [ "${CI_PROJECT_NAME}" == "test" ]; then echo I am a CI job in the test project; fi
    - echo done
```

The first script line will only run in the `test` project.  The second script line will run in every project.